# How to supply multiple values for where clause as parameters to SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, parameter-passing, agent

Newbie so please be gentle with me.

I have a dtsx package being called by a SQL Server Agent job. The package has a variable defined as Int32. The job supplies a numeric value at run time. All is good provided only one value is supplied. But, of course there's a "but", I'd like the job to supply two or more numeric codes which will populate the parameter in the OLE DB where clause:

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DY, [at].TRANSACTION_TIME, DATEADD([DAY], - 7, GETDATE())) <= 0)
AND   ([at].PROMOTION_ID in ( **?** ))
```

Tried defining the variable as a string and not surprisingly this failed as query probably reading variable in as a single value with a comma in it.

Suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these resources will provide some starting point-

[Using dynamic SQL in an OLE DB Source component](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/12/09/SSIS_3A00_-Using-dynamic-SQL-in-an-OLE-DB-Source-component.aspx)

[OLE DB Source SQLCommand](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1117430-147-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Vikramsinh. You're a diamond! SSIS Junkie page sorted it in minutes.